# Error while running bin/magento setup:di:compile - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3.4, fatal-error, setup-di-compile

this is driving me insane.

I am receiving the following error while running compile:

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice, because the name is already in use in /home/hucklebo/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php on line 212

Any pointers how to resolve or debug this this as I can't complete the compilation process after adding new modules.

The compile stops at: Class: /home/hucklebo/public_html/generated/code

Thank you. Magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, it seems that some changes have been made in some files in the vendor directory (**which should be avoided**).

Open the file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php`, and verify that the class name is `Shipment`. In your case, it might be `Invoice` instead, which is not normal.

To be sure you are working on a sane vendor directory, you should reset it with composer.

To do so, follow these steps :

1. Backup your current `vendor` directory, by renaming it into `vendor_old` (so you can get back to it if you have some problem, or if you had some development made in it)
2. Run the command `composer install`, to reinstall all the composer packages properly
3. Clear the generated files : `rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/*`
4. Try again to compile it : `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: thank you, i'll try this. You may be right that this is due to historical changes to the vendor directory

Comment: In that case, you should be careful to either get any changes made in the vendor directory and implement them properly into modules/theme. Or if there are few of them, apply them as patches.

Comment: following this has enabled me to complete the compile process:  Open the file vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php, and verify that the class name is Shipment. In your case, it might be Invoice instead, which is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Running composer install generates:

Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

Problem 1
- magento/inventory-composer-installer is locked to version 1.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Problem 2
- magento/magento-composer-installer is locked to version 0.1.13 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/magento-composer-installer 0.1.13 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Problem 3
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Problem 4
- magento/magento-composer-installer 0.1.13 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- msp/twofactorauth 3.1.2 requires magento/magento-composer-installer * -> satisfiable by magento/magento-composer-installer[0.1.13].
- msp/twofactorauth is locked to version 3.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.